# Barracuda.com and crawling / pinger services causing unusual load on web servers

Tags: web-crawler, barracuda

I recently received a large number of hits on my home page from **64.235.153.8**. It revolves to **barracuda.com** I know Barracuda as an enterprise class spam detection/prevention solution. 
Do they also offer some kind of bot/crawling or pinger services that could be detected as unusual load on web servers?

Comment: Can you post a request? What kind of UserAgent etc?